# How to use transition effect on accordion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accordion, styled-components

I created simple accordion using React and styled components. I have a problem with making the effect so that the lower part can slide out slowly and not pop up right away. I used a transition but I don't know why it doesn't work in my case. There is part of my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-blackwell-v78wt?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Have you checked out the answer?

Answer (score 1):

For the best effect you'll need to transition the `max-height` from `0px` to the height of the content and vice versa. You'll need to use the `useRef` and `useEffect` hooks to select the elements and manually set the styles on them.

You'll also need an inner wrapper that knows the height of the content. This will be a reference for setting the `max-height` on the collapsing container.

With the `onTransitionEnd` event listener you can remove the `max-height` property when the accordion is expanded. This enables the element to resize responsively based on the content.

The height of the content is determined with the `getBoundingClientRect()` function. It returns an object with the height, width (and more) of an element. With this you can determine the height of the content container.

The example below is a workable example based on your code.

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Accordion = () => {
  const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(false);
  const [isAnimating, setIsAnimating] = useState(false);
  const collapseRef = useRef(null);
  const contentRef = useRef(null);

  const handleClick = () => {
    /**
     * isAnimating prevents the accordion from changing
     * state when it is in the middle of a transition.
     */
    if (!isAnimating) {
      setIsAnimating(true);
      setIsExpanded((isExpanded) => !isExpanded);
    }
  };

  const handleTransition = () => {
    if (isExpanded) {
      /**
       * Removing the max-height when expanded makes sure
       * that the element still resizes responsively correct.
       */
      collapseRef.current.style.maxHeight = "";
    }
    setIsAnimating(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const { height } = contentRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();
    collapseRef.current.style.maxHeight = `${height}px`;
    if (!isExpanded) {
      /**
       * This makes sure that the element first is expanded
       * and in the next frame paint is transitioned to 0px.
       * Otherwise the 0px height would overwrite to dynamic height
       * and there'd be no transition.
       */
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        collapseRef.current.style.maxHeight = "0px";
      });
    }
  }, [isExpanded]);

  return (
    <ContentWrapper onClick={handleClick}>
      <TitleCard>
        <h2>Example text</h2>
      </TitleCard>
      <DescriptionCard
        ref={collapseRef}
        isVisible={isExpanded}
        style={{ maxHeight: "0px" }}
        onTransitionEnd={handleTransition}
      >
        <DescriptionContent ref={contentRef}>
          <p>Example text 2</p>
          <p>Now it expands based on the height of the</p>
          <h3>content.</h3>
          <p>Now it expands based on the height of the</p>
          <h3>content.</h3>
        </DescriptionContent>
      </DescriptionCard>
    </ContentWrapper>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Accordion />
    </div>
  );
}

const DescriptionContent = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
`;

const DescriptionCard = styled.div`
  background: grey;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  transition: max-height 0.35s;
`;

const TitleCard = styled.div`
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 4.8rem;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 1.5em;
`;

const ContentWrapper = styled.div`
  border-radius: 16px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
`;
```

Comment: Hi Emiel.  Thanks for the useful snippet. I was trying to convert this into a reusable hook, with a callback ref, as shown here: https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node. I got stuck on the fact that we need the click event, from another node. Do you know how we could make a generic hook with your above code as the backbone?

Comment: Also, perhaps a small typo: Do you need the `isVisible` prop on the `DescriptionCard`?

Comment: One more question, if I may: What's the program flow here? When a user clicks, does it go like this: handleClick -> useEffect -> requestAnimationFrame (if collapsing) -> transition happens -> handleTransition?

Comment: Regarding the reusability tip you gave above, how would you attach the ref to the children? Do you just forget about the contentRef and replace it with the collapseRef (so the height is calculated from the collapseRef, and not the contentRef)?

Comment: Ah, you would keep the `DescriptionContent`, and put the children within. I see. Would it not work to measure the height of the `DescriptionCard` instead, so you could remove the `contentRef` and only use the `collapseRef`? I.e. make this modification: `const { height } = collapseRef.current.getBoundingClientRect();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253412/discussion-between-magnus-and-emiel-zuurbier).